# PySpark Map transformation passing a function Error Caused by: java.io.EOFException

Tags: pyspark

I am having some trouble when I tried to pass a function to the map method of a Spark RDD. My problem appears to be in the function maybe, but not sure about it.

My functions are something like this:

```
def add_h3_hash_column(row):
    rowDict = row.asDict()
    hash = h3.geo_to_h3(
        rowDict["latitude"], rowDict["longitude"], resolution
    )
    rowDict[f"h3_hash_{res}"] = str(hash)
    return rowDict


def h3_hash_generator(spark: SparkSession, resolution, sdf: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    """Creates a new column in a DataFrame with the Hexagon hashes of the given resolution
    that map to a geographic point (latitude, longitude).

    :param resolution: the h3 resolution for the hexagons.
    :param df: DataFrame containing two columns named "latitude" and "longitude".
    :return: Returns the DataFrame with a new column with h3 hashes of desire resolution.
    """
    sdf_w_hash = sdf.rdd.map(add_h3_hash_column)
    sdf = spark.createDataFrame(sdf_w_hash)
    return sdf
```

I have tried other things also, like returning a Row() object in from add_h3_hash_column, or by simplifying the function to just return ("Hello") and still received the same error.

When executing the code I received the following error:

```
objc[54297]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[54297]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
22/10/28 13:47:48 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 102)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:550)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:539)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:635)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$runJob$1(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:642)
        ... 29 more
22/10/28 13:47:48 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 102) (ip-192-168-1-152.eu-west-1.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:550)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:539)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:635)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$runJob$1(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:642)
        ... 29 more

22/10/28 13:47:48 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "partner_stores/runners/concept_runners/main_concepts.py", line 33, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "partner_stores/runners/concept_runners/main_concepts.py", line 23, in main
    build_stg_h3_store_addresses(spark, args)
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/repositories/partner-data-mesh/data_products/partner_stores/partner_stores/runners/concept_runners/transformations/build_stg_h3_store_addresses.py", line 45, in build_stg_h3_store_addresses
    stg_h3_store_addresses = h3_hash_generator(
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/repositories/partner-data-mesh/data_products/partner_stores/partner_stores/utils/common.py", line 98, in h3_hash_generator
    sdf = spark.createDataFrame(sdf_w_hash)
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 675, in createDataFrame
    return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 698, in _create_dataframe
    rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 486, in _createFromRDD
    struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio, names=schema)
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 460, in _inferSchema
    first = rdd.first()
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1586, in first
    rs = self.take(1)
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1566, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 1233, in runJob
    sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/danielteixeira/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/partner-stores-hpriuLoD-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 102) (ip-192-168-1-152.eu-west-1.compute.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:550)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:539)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:635)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$runJob$1(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:642)
        ... 29 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2303)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2252)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2251)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2251)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1124)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1124)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1124)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2490)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2432)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2421)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:550)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:539)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:635)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:470)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.$anonfun$runJob$1(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:642)
        ... 29 more
```

But if I do not pass a function, it works:

```
def h3_hash_generator(spark: SparkSession, resolution, sdf: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    sdf_w_hash = sdf.rdd.map(lambda x:
                             (x.id,
                              x.store_id,
                              h3.geo_to_h3(x.latitude, x.longitude, resolution)
                              ))
    sdf = spark.createDataFrame(sdf_w_hash)
    return sdf
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `add_h3_hash_column` is just a python function (it has nothing to do with PySpark).

When you do this: `sdf.rdd.map(add_h3_hash_column)`, the `map` function is called for the RDD object, coming from PySpark library. This is a syntax issue as `map` function is executed for each record, but it doesn't know from the above expression about the parameters that needs to go in.

The second way you used map function is the right way of calling the `map` function on an RDD.

> PySpark map (`map()`) is an RDD transformation that is used to apply
> the transformation function (lambda) on every element of RDD/DataFrame
> and returns a new RDD.

The `lambda expression` you just wrote means, for each record `x` you are creating what comes after the colon `:`, in this case, a tuple with 3 elements which are `id`, `store_id` and `geo_to_h3` (the hash value).

You can refer to this [link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-map-transformation/).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Kumar, thanks for your answer. One question though, in the link you shared in the section "PySpark map() Example with DataFrame", they use a function in the end, that is not the same as what I tried to do?